# How to call method using scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, .net

I'm trying to understand a specific line of code from visual studio .net framework, based on what i understand, it is assigning the method that belongs to the class double into the 'firstDigit' variable.
I tried this thing out on my own.

```
#include <iostream>
class sampleClass {
    int a;
    public:

    class sampleInsideClass {
        public:
        int b;
    
        int displayThis (int a){
        this->b = a;
        return (this->b);
        }
    };
};

int main() {

   sampleClass::sampleInsideClass obj;
   std::cout << sampleClass::sampleInsideClass::displayThis(5); //this is producing error: cannot call member function 'int sampleClass::sampleInsideClass::displayThis(int)' without object

return 0;
}
```

why doesn't it work on my own code?

```
//-----this is the code from visual studio---------------------------//

//variable = class::method();
firstDigit = Double::Parse(txtDisplay->Text);
```

Comment: `Parse` is a [static member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) of `Double`. `displayThis` is a non-static member of `sampleInsideClass`, and requires an instance of `sampleInsideClass` to be called on, as in `obj.displayThis(5)`

Answer (score 0):

Look at your definition of `displayThis`

```
int displayThis (int a){
    this->b = a;
    return (this->b);
}
```

When you call `sampleClass::sampleInsideClass::displayThis(5)` ,
what do you think the object pointed by `this` pointer is ? There is no object in memory on which you are calling `displayThis`.

You can do two things,

- Make your function static. A static function is a member function of a class that can be called even when an object of the class is not initialized, like `Double::Parse`. But the catch is, static functions cannot access any class members `this-> b`.
- Create and object instance and then call `displayThis`